# Como faço para preencher um listbox c# mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

Como faço para preencher um ListBox com C# e mysql e ao mesmo tempo colocar o valor de cada registro?

até o momento eu consegui configurar para aparecer o nome, mas não o codigo de cada um:

```
Mat_sel.Items.Add(reader["mat_nome"]).ToString();
```

Comment: Qual é o tipo do objeto Mat_sel e qual é o nome da coluna de valor que você quer adicionar?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como dar um select para pegar só alguns registro mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267361/como-dar-um-select-para-pegar-s%c3%b3-alguns-registro-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a propriedade `DisplayMember` do `ListBox` para escolher o que mostrar.

#### 1. Crie uma classe

Primeiramente, crie uma classe que servirá como o objeto da sua lista. Por exemplo, uma classe chamada `SomeData`, que irá armazenar o texto e o valor que você buscará do banco de dados:

```
public class SomeData
{
    public string Value { get; set; };
    public string Text { get; set; };
}
```

#### 2. Crie o ListBox

Agora, crie seu ListBox da seguinte forma (observe que utilizei `reader["mat_codigo"]).ToString()` pois não sei qual é o nome da coluna do código que está no seu banco de dados):

```
List<SomeData> data = new List<SomeData>();
data.Add(new SomeData() { Value = reader["mat_codigo"]).ToString(), Text = reader["mat_nome"]).ToString()});
data.Add(new SomeData() { Value = reader["mat_codigo"]).ToString(), Text = reader["mat_nome"]).ToString()});
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
listBox1.DataSource = data;
```

Onde o `"Text"` de `listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text"` é o nome da propriedade `Text` da sua classe `SomeData`.

#### 3. Acessando dados do item selecionado

Quando o usuário selecionar um item, você pode ler o valor (ou qualquer outra propriedade) do objeto selecionado:

```
string value = (listBox1.SelectedItem as SomeData).Value;
string text = (listBox1.SelectedItem as SomeData).Text;
```

Traduzido e adaptado de: [Make ListBox items have a different value than item text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867514/make-listbox-items-have-a-different-value-than-item-text)

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou muito.