# Como dar um select para pegar só alguns registro mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Na tabela turma_materia tem as seguintes informações.

```
CODIGO   |   MATERIA   |   TURMA
---------------------------------
1        |      1      |    2
```

Na tabela Materia tem as seguintes informações

```
CODIGO   |   NOME DA MATERIA
  1      |       PORTUGUES
  2      |       MATEMATICA
  3      |       INGLES
```

Eu quero pegar o nome das materias (2-MATEMATICA, 3-INGLES) que não está relacionado na turma codigo 2
até agora só consegue o codigo abaixo.

```
SELECT MA.mat_nome, TM.turma_tuma, TM.materia_tuma FROM materia MA 
LEFT JOIN turma_materia TM ON MA.mat_id=TM.materia_tuma
WHERE TM.turma_tuma<>1
```

Comment: Informação complementar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70

Comment: SELECT
  *
FROM
  materia
WHERE
  codigo NOT IN (
    SELECT
      materia
    FROM
      turma_materia
    WHERE
      turma = 2
  )

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, eu conseguir no seguinte script
SELECT * FROM materia WHERE materia.mat_id NOT IN (SELECT turma_materia.materia_tuma FROM turma_materia WHERE turma_materia.turma_tuma=1);